# Blackberry Packaging Project Issue

Tags: blackberry

I was wondering if anybody knows how to resolve this issue... I have been going at this for many hours with no luck.

```
Packaging project BBClient.OS50
C:\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\bin\rapc.exe -convertpng -quiet codename=deliverables\Standard\5.0.0\BBClient -sourceroot=C:\Users\z\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BBClient.OS50\.locale_interfaces;C:\Users\z\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BBClient.OS50\src -import=C:\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar C:\Users\z\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BBClient.OS50\deliverables\Standard\5.0.0\BBClient.jad C:\Users\z\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BBClient.OS50\deliverables\Standard\5.0.0\BBClient.rapc C:\Users\z\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BBClient.OS50\bin
Packaging project BBClient.OS50 failed (took 0.057 seconds) 

Packaging project BBClient.OS50
C:\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\bin\rapc.exe -convertpng -quiet codename=deliverables\Standard\5.0.0\BBClient -sourceroot=C:\Users\z\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BBClient.OS50\.locale_interfaces;C:\Users\z\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BBClient.OS50\src -import=C:\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar C:\Users\z\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BBClient.OS50\deliverables\Standard\5.0.0\BBClient.jad C:\Users\z\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BBClient.OS50\deliverables\Standard\5.0.0\BBClient.rapc C:\Users\z\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BBClient.OS50\bin
Packaging project BBClient.OS50 failed (took 0.01 seconds)
```

Comment: Are you building this from Eclipse, using the Eclipse BlackBerry Plugin?  Which version (e.g. 1.5, 2.0, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to solve it.. it was a jdk problem, it was installed but not the variables were not mapped properly